# Flutter : Show an Alert Dialog after an async Api call

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is the code to get the Login response. If there is an error I want to show an Alert dialog saying that there was an error during Login.

```
Future<String> login(String username, String password) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> params = {
       'username': username,
       'password': password,
    };

    final response = await http.post('apiurl', body: params);

    if (response.statusCode != 200)
       throw Exception(response.body);

    return response.body;
}
```

I'm adding the code from where the call to *login* happens. There is a TODO in the *_loginController* where I want to Show an Alert Dialog which shows the error.

```
class LoginWidgetState extends State<LoginWidget> {
  var _usernameController = new TextEditingController();

  var _passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  void _loginButtonClickHandler() {
    var username = _usernameController.text;
    var password = _passwordController.text;

    login(username, password).then((response) {

    }).catchError((e) {
      //TODO : show an Alert Here
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var container = Center(
      child: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "username",
          ),
          controller: _usernameController,
        ),
        TextField(
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "password"),
          controller: _passwordController,
        ),
        RawMaterialButton(
          onPressed: _loginButtonClickHandler,
          child: Text("Login"),
        )
       ],
     ),
    ),
   );

   return container;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51778232/5305962) to show the dialog.

Send `context` to `_loginButtonClickHandler` and you are done. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

To give more context to the accepted answer...

[image]

If you make a remote API call like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51842018/3681880):

```
login(username, password).then((response) {

}).catchError((e) {
  //TODO : show an Alert Here
});
```

then you can replace the TODO with this (if you are calling it from a button click):

```
_showAlertDialog(context);
```

Or this (if you are calling it from within a `build()` method or `initState()`:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _showAlertDialog(context));
```

Where the method is defined as

```
void _showNewVersionAvailableDialog(BuildContext context) {
  final alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Error"),
    content: Text("There was an error during login."),
    actions: [FlatButton(child: Text("OK"), onPressed: () {})],
  );

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

#### Notes

- You need to have a reference to the `BuildContext`.
- For more info about addPostFrameCallback, read [this article](https://www.didierboelens.com/faq/week2/).

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This will help you!

```
  Future<String> login(String username, String password) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> params = {
       'username': username,
       'password': password,
    };

    final response = await http.post('apiurl', body: params);

    if (response.statusCode != 200)
    {
      throw Exception(response.body);
    }
    else 
    {
      showWhateverFunction();
    }
    return response.body;
}
```

Comment: I want to have common method to make an Api call. In that case I just want to throw the Exception and leave it to the caller to handle it accordingly.

Comment: then try try catch!

Comment: I'm already throwing it. I just need to complete the TODO part

Answer (score 0):

You can use RFlutter Alert library for that. It is easily customizable and easy-to-use alert/popup dialog library for Flutter. I hope it will help you.

Example alert with RFlutter Alert:

```
Alert(context: context, title: "RFLUTTER", desc: "Flutter is awesome.").show();
```

*I'm one of developer of RFlutter Alert.